# Am I not using the _GET function properly to open another page?

Tags: php

I'm asking this because my teacher was displeased with how it worked. By that I mean ,when I typed in the query string to change sites, instead of typing ?page=flight and it staying that way it changed to../flight-details.php which is the direct page name.

Router.php:

```
<?php

$nav =array("home"=>"home.php",
    "flight"=>"flight-detail.php",
    "order"=>"order-flight.php",
    "testimonial"=>"add-testimonial.php");


if ( isset ($_GET) )
{
    header('Location: ' .  $nav[$_GET['page']]);
}
else
    {
        header('Location:index.php');
    }
```

Comment: The superglobal array `$_GET` will always be set, regardless how you opened the php script (unless you do some changes in the php configuration). So `isset($_GET)` will always be true.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- `$_GET` is a superglobal array, right now you are just checking whether the array is set or not. Your `if` condition should be like this:

  ```
  if(isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], array_keys($nav))){ ...
  ```

  Otherwise you would get *undefined index* error if someone types anything other than the following four combinations, `?page=home&...`, `?page=flight&...`, `?page=order&...` and `?page=testimonial&...`.
- `header(...);` is not enough to redirect the user to a different page, use `exit();` immediately after `header(...);` statement.

So your code should be like this:

```
$nav =array("home"=>"home.php",
    "flight"=>"flight-detail.php",
    "order"=>"order-flight.php",
    "testimonial"=>"add-testimonial.php");

if(isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], array_keys($nav))){
    header('Location: ' . $nav[$_GET['page']]);
}else{
    header('Location:index.php');
}
exit();
```

Here's the relevant reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: It says I'm being redirected too many times now,and even when I do ?page=flight it still changes to flight-details.php in the header,which shouldn't be happening according to my teacher

Comment: @Auridas, That's probably because you are loading `index.php` page without URL query string, either comment out `header('Location:index.php');` line or remove `else` block altogether, like this: `if(...){ ... }else{ // header('Location:index.php'); }` or `if(...){ ...}`(no `else` block)

Comment: @Auridas, Above comment is to avoid recursive redirects. But as far as *when I do ?page=flight it still changes to flight-details.php in the header,which shouldn't be happening* is concerned, what's the behavior you want?

Comment: That's just it ,I'm not sure,cause my teacher likes being vague about it,aka not being very helpful when anyone is stuck,but he doesn't like the fact that after I type in ?page=flight ,lets say,it immediately changes to flight-details.php....Though ,I noticed my classmate used $_Server if i'm not mistaken ,would it change anything?      also,removing the else part fixed it

Comment: @Auridas, We cannot be very helpful unless you tell us what exactly you want instead of redirection.

Comment: What I want is for it to stay as ?page=flight but for  flight-testimonials.php to be displayed...also,I should note that these _GET values should also become clickable links...I'm sorry if I'm not being very clear ,but this is just as vague for me as it is for you,probably :/